# Insert new rows with designated carried over values

Tags: pandas

Say I have the following dataframe:

```
    value  length
 0   2.4     3  
 1   5.3     6  
 2   17.1    8 
 3   11.9    11

df = pd.DataFrame([(2.4, 3),(5.3, 6),(17.1, 8),(11.9, 11)], columns=['value', 'length'])
```

Column `length` is of integer and strictly increasing. I would like to insert rows where there there is a gap of more than `1` in column `length`, and the values of the new rows take the value immediately before it. Here is the expected output:

```
    value  length
 0   2.4     3  
 1   2.4     4
 2   2.4     5
 3   5.3     6
 4   5.3     7  
 5   17.1    8 
 6   17.1    9
 7   17.1    10
 8   11.9    11
```

What would be a good way to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us do `set_index` + `reindex`

```
out = df.set_index('length').\
          reindex(range(df.length.min(),df.length.max()+1),method = 'ffill').reset_index()
   length  value
0       3    2.4
1       4    2.4
2       5    2.4
3       6    5.3
4       7    5.3
5       8   17.1
6       9   17.1
7      10   17.1
8      11   11.9
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`df['length'].diff`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.diff.html) to compute the number of repeats for each index, and [`df.index.repeat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.repeat.html) to repeat the items of the index per those values. Then you can index the dataframe using the resulting repeated index, and use [`df.assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) to add a column containing a range from the smallest value of the `length` column to the largest value (both inclusive).

```
df = (
    df.loc[
        df.index.repeat(
            df['length']
            .diff()
            .shift(-1, fill_value=1)
        )
    ]
    .reset_index(drop=True)
    .assign(length=np.arange(
        df['length'].min(),
        df['length'].max() + 1
    ))
)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
   value  length
0    2.4       3
1    2.4       4
2    2.4       5
3    5.3       6
4    5.3       7
5   17.1       8
6   17.1       9
7   17.1      10
8   11.9      11
```

Compact version:

```
df = df.loc[df.index.repeat(df['length'].diff().shift(-1, fill_value=1))].reset_index(drop=True).assign(length=np.arange(df['length'].min(), df['length'].max()+1))
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. Got to learn new functions from your solution. I think BENY's solution is a little more convenient and robust.

Comment: You're welcome. I'm glad to help :) I personally prefer Psidom's - it's smart thinking to use ffil :)

Answer (score 1):

Another option using `reindex`:

```
df.set_index('length')
  .reindex(np.arange(df.length.min(), df.length.max() + 1))
  .ffill()
  .reset_index()

   length  value
0       3    2.4
1       4    2.4
2       5    2.4
3       6    5.3
4       7    5.3
5       8   17.1
6       9   17.1
7      10   17.1
8      11   11.9
```

Running example: https://akuiper.com/console/fsm1iI6PIhxA

Comment: Thanks. Your solution looks similar to BENY's. For some reason, I want to to change the granuality from ```1``` to, say ```0.2``` with ```df.set_index('length').reindex(np.arange(df.length.min(), df.length.max() + 0.2, step=0.2)).ffill().reset_index()```, it does not work. But his does (if I replace ```range``` with ```np.arange```. Both work equally for my question, though.

Comment: Here is a modification based on BENY's solution ```out = df.set_index('length').reindex(np.arange(df.length.min(), df.length.max()+0.2, step=0.2),method = 'ffill').reset_index()```

Comment: Yeah, it looks like `reindex` with `method = 'ffill'` can handle floating point index better.